# Pandas: how set a color of lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 dataframe and I try to impose one graph from dataframe to another graph.

Parts of dataframes looks like

```
month   bank_card   unique_users                percentage  percentage1
2015-03 Вклады (депозиты)   1798899 0,003426124 6163,250294 0,03902125  3,902124963 1,951062481
2015-04 Вклады (депозиты)   1667598 0,003426124 5713,396841 0,036173102 3,617310246 1,808655123
2015-03 Дебетовые карты 71617   0,003426124 245,3686929 0,001553497 0,155349735 0,077674868
2015-04 Дебетовые карты 71241   0,003426124 244,0804704 0,001545341 0,154534126 0,077267063
2015-03 Ипотека (жилищный кредит)   1635929 0,003426124 5604,894933 0,035486147 3,548614674 1,774307337
2015-04 Ипотека (жилищный кредит)   1269010 0,003426124 4347,785093 0,027527035 2,752703514 1,376351757
2015-03 Кредитные карты 623978  0,003426124 2137,825743 0,013535169 1,353516862 0,676758431
2015-04 Кредитные карты 570617  0,003426124 1955,004363 0,012377676 1,237767568 0,618883784
```

and next

```
month   bank_card   unique_users    all_time    all coeff   unique_users1   percentage
2015-03 Вклады (депозиты)   355 1235    18459   4,16663958  1479,157051 1,923181104
2015-03 Дебетовые карты 116 399 18459   4,16663958  483,3301912 0,628419741
2015-03 Ипотека (жилищный кредит)   109 347 18459   4,16663958  454,1637142 0,59049786
2015-03 Кредитные карты 99  425 18459   4,16663958  412,4973184 0,536323745
2015-03 Потребительские кредиты 159 674 18459   4,16663958  662,4956932 0,861368438
2015-04 Вклады (депозиты)   394 2147    18459   4,16663958  1641,655994 2,134460155
2015-04 Дебетовые карты 97  212 18459   4,16663958  404,1640392 0,525488921
2015-04 Ипотека (жилищный кредит)   175 734 18459   4,16663958  729,1619264 0,948047023
2015-04 Кредитные карты 140 624 18459   4,16663958  583,3295411 0,758437619
2015-04 Потребительские кредиты 268 1240    18459   4,16663958  1116,659407 1,451866298
```

I get next graph:
[image: graph]

But I need to set a common color to one category, but there are all colors are different

I use code

```
result = pd.read_excel('yandex.xlsx')
result1 = pd.read_excel('check_norm.xlsx')
idf = result.set_index('month')
idf1 = result1.set_index('month')
idf = idf.groupby('bank_card')['percentage1'].plot(title='Люди, искавшие информацию на страницах банков', linestyle='--', colors=['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'])
idf1 = idf1.groupby('bank_card')['percentage'].plot(title='Люди, искавшие информацию на страницах банков', colors=['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'y'])
plt.ylabel('Users, %')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

It returns `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'r'`